# simple query on scaffolding rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, actionmailer, mailer

So my simple question is, i want to call a mailer if particular column is updated in database with the form based on below controller. But i dont know how to take the column name ... I am doing like `if @style.category` after `if @style.save` but not working.

Controller

```
  def new
    @style = Style.new
    @users = User.where('username <> ?', current_user.username)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @style }
    end
  end


    def create
        @style = Style.new(params[:style])
        @style.sender = current_user

        respond_to do |format|
          if @style.save,
            ### want to call mailer here , based on if column "category" is updated or not 
            if @style.receiver
            format.html { redirect_to user_path(@style.receiver.username), notice: "successs!"}
            else
              format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Success!' }
            end
```

Comment: Remove the comma after `@style.save`

Comment: Use consistent indentation levels. The ruby community suggests 2 spaces for each indentation.

Comment: Hi Kirti, can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

add a after_save callback inside the model can help

```
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :send_email

  def send_email
    if changed_attributes.has_key?('category')
      call the mailer here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hi, can you tell me how to access the column names in my scenario ..once form is create ?

Comment: the changed_attributes variable is a hash, it track all the columns that has been changed since the last save operation. just print it out and play with it.